# Filter table rows with multiple conditions from related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Product related with another table named ProductAttribute.
ProductAttribute:

```
ID,
ProductId,
Value,
AttributeID
```

And I need to get all products with these conditions:

```
AttributeID=1017 AND Value='false'
AttributeID=1011 AND Value='200'
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT T0.*
FROM Product T0
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute T1
    ON T1.ProductID = T0.ID
WHERE (T1.AttributeID = 1011 AND T1.Value = 'false')
    AND
    (T1.AttributeID = 1017 AND T1.Value = '200')
```

But the result was empty.
And tried this query

```
SELECT T0.*
FROM Product T0
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute T1
    ON T1.ProductID = T0.ID
WHERE (T1.AttributeID = 1011 AND T1.Value = 'false')
    OR
    (T1.AttributeID = 1017 AND T1.Value = '200')
```

But the result was every row has one of the two conditions.
I need the rows that fulfill the two conditions together. 
this is the ProductAttribute table's data:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] i.e. including sample data (ideally as DDL+DML) and desired results.

Comment: Do you have products that holds those attributes IDs?

Comment: If you can provide some sample data (maybe some print screens) showing what values you have in both tables, I guess we can sort it out. Otherwise, we can only guess the query... as you did.

Comment: @DaleK - I said maybe, not necessarily :D.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` in a *derived table* (the subquery) to make sure both attributes are there. Then `JOIN`.

```
SELECT T0.*
FROM Product T0
INNER JOIN
(
    select ProductID 
    from ProductAttribute
    WHERE (AttributeID = 1011 AND Value = 'false')
       OR (AttributeID = 1017 AND Value = '200')
    group by ProductID
    having count(distinct AttributeID) = 2
) T1 ON T1.ProductID = T0.ID
```

(I'd rather chose table aliases that make sense, like `p` for Product and `pa` for ProductAttribute...)

Comment: this query worked well, please would you explain the line of 'having count (distinct AttributeId)=2, because I didn't get it

Comment: `count(distinct AttributeID)` counts the number of distinct (different) AttributeID's for a ProductID. Used to make sure both 1011 and 1017 are there for a ProductID.